# A question about how to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Excuse me, my question is, will there be a problem if I download the Ubuntu file from here and put it on CD?

I mean, if I download the file here and put it in a CD, can I install it with the same CD, or do I have to buy it?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "from here", but generaly you can download ubuntu from anywhere. It is free.

Comment: Ubuntu have tutorials:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview  writing dvd on macos 
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-macos#1-overview
writing dvd on windows https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1-overview
writing dvd on ubuntu https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/14022

Comment: CD's maximum capacity is 700 MB but, if talking about Ubuntu Desktop edition, you need at least 1.5 GB.

Comment: or you can write to thumb-drive too https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Ubuntu is free to install and use, but you will need to use a DVD or USB stick because the size is bigger than what a CD can hold.  If you like Ubuntu, they do accept donations.